# Why Setting Input width does not match content exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

My goal is to have the HTML input elements dynamically change to fit their contents.  I have something working pretty well, see [my jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/FwMBR/1/).

My problem is: you can see that when you type many characters into the text field, the width is actually always a certain percentage (or so) longer than the text content.

[image]

See the little space to the right of the last "j" in the input field?  I wish the input would just snug up exactly with the end of the text value.  The longer the text value is typed into the input, the more drastic the problem.

I am setting the width of the input from the width of the adjacent `<span>` element.  Anyone know why the width I am getting is actually a little larger than the width of the text in the input?

**UPDATE**

I fixed the problem using the answer below and here is some working code with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/FwMBR/13/.

```
$('input').width('10px').keyup(function(){

    $('#a').remove();

    $(this).after('<span id="a">'+$(this).val()+'</span>');

    $('#a').css({
        'font-family':$(this).css('font-family'),
        'font-size':$(this).css('font-size')
    });

    $(this).width($('#a').width());

});
```

Comment: The `span` and `input` fonts are different. You'd need them to be the same. Also, there is padding on an input box by default (at least in Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the font of your test span is not the same as the font of the text box; thus the character widths don't match. You should either

- set the font and font size for the text box to the same as the test span's or
- find the text box font and font size and set them to the test span.

The latter looks better (keeps native text box font), but is harder to implement, so I wrote [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ3vD/) to do it.

```
var computed = window.getComputedStyle($('input')[0]);
$('#a').css({
    'font-family': computed.fontFamily, 
    'font-size': computed.fontSize
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/PeQXJ/

css :

```
.myinput , body
{
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif; 
    font-size:14px;
}
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="myinput">
```

js:

```
$('input').width('10px').keyup(function(){

    $('#a').remove();

    $(this).after('<span id="a">'+$(this).val()+'</span>');

    $(this).width($('#a').width());

});;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

CSS :

```
.mytext {
    padding-right: 0px! important;

 }
```

HTML :

```
 <input type="text" class="mytext">
```

This Is **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FwMBR/10/)**

Comment: It looks like the problem still persists in your fiddle example.  I am  pretty sure it is because the fonts are different.

Comment: do u tried with same font for both - input and display ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this. This will work as you want

```
$('input').width('10px').keydown(function(){

    $('#a').remove();

    $(this).after('<span id="a">'+$(this).val()+'</span>');

    $(this).width($('#a').width());

});;
```

** Use same font in field and HTML page.

Comment: How is it different and what does it do differently to fix the problem?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi which browser you are using. It's working in chrome.

Comment: @Pietu1998 if you push any key continuously then the code snippet in question would show some problems. My code just resolve that.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari press the character 'f' for a long time. :)